# How to modify firebase database so that i can set a read or unread status

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I need to show the count of unread messages from firebase in the notification bell.
I am done with displaying all contents in my collection in my web application.But when a new message arrives i need to give a feedback to user by showing the unread message count in notification bell .From my understanding,for that i need to set a read/unread status in firebase collection.Is there any alternative way for showing the count of unread messages in my **React** Web Application?

i am using firebase package of npm for displaying messages.

Below is the sample data in my firebase collection.

```
name:"John Doe",
message:"you got a new appointment"
```

*i am new to* **firebase**.*Please help me with some logic to sort out this problem.*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would want to use a status flag (read: boolean), **unless** you would not mind writing all new messages to a particular path and moving them to another path after it is read.

Something like below

```
/user/unread-msg => all new messages come here
/user/read-msg   => messages are moved here after being read.
```

This I believe would be less efficient than using a simple flag.

You could use a firebase cloud function to maintain the count of child elements in a particular path like `/user/unread-msg` or `/user/read-msg` so that you don't have to download the entire data to get the count.

Refer the sample code at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count